# Got an extra line on python plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, fft

i'm using pyplot to show the FFT of the signal 'a', here the code:

```
myFFT = numpy.fft.fft(a)
x = numpy.arange(len(a))
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.plot(numpy.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[-1]), myFFT)
fig2.show()
```

and i get this figure
[image]

There is a line from the begin to the end of the signal in the frequency domain. How i can remove this line? AM I doing something wrong with pyplot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [constant lines occur in plot of fft with scipy.fftpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49612848/constant-lines-occur-in-plot-of-fft-with-scipy-fftpack)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `plt.plot(numpy.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[-1])`: the first and last points are the same, hence the graph "makes a loop"

You can do `plt.plot(sorted(numpy.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[-1])),myFFT)` or `plt.plot(myFFT)`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `sorted`, you might want to use `np.fft.fftshift` to center you 0th frequency, this deals properly with odd- and even-size signals. Most importantly, you need to apply the transform on both x and y vectors you are plotting.

```
plt.plot(np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[-1])), np.fft.fftshift(myFFT))
```

You might also want to display the amplitude or phase of the FFT (`np.abs` or `np.angle`) - as-is, you are just plotting the real-part.