# np.fft.fft not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, fft

I'm trying to use python 3.x to do an fft from some data. But when I plot I get my original data (?) not the data's fft. I'm using matlab so I can compare the results.
I've already tried many examples from this site but nothing seems to work. I'm not used to work with python. How can I get a plot similar to matlab's? I don't care if I get -f/2 to f/2 or 0 to f/2 spectrum.
[My data](https://github.com/mat1554/Eletronica/blob/master/sinal2.mat)

```
import scipy.io
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mat = scipy.io.loadmat('sinal2.mat')

sinal2 = mat['sinal2']

Fs = 1000

L = 1997

T = 1.0/1000.0

fsig = np.fft.fft(sinal2)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(sinal2), 1/Fs)

plt.figure()
plt.plot( freq, np.abs(fsig))
plt.figure()
plt.plot(freq, np.angle(fsig))
plt.show()
```

FFT from python:
[image: FFT(?) from python]

FFT from matlab:
[image: FFT from matlab]

Comment: Gosh, took me ages to find the problem! THANKS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The imported signal `sinal2` has a size `(1997,1)`. In case of 2 dimensional arrays like this, [`numpy.fft.fft`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fft.html#numpy.fft.fft) by default computes the FFT along the last axis. In this case that means computing 1997 FFTs of size 1. As you may know a 1-point FFT is an identity mapping (meaning the FFT of a single value gives the same value), hence the resulting 2D array is identical to the original array.

To avoid this, you can either specify the other axis explicitly:

```
fsig = np.fft.fft(sinal2, axis=0)
```

Or otherwise convert the data to a single dimensional array, then compute the FFT of a 1D array:

```
sinal2 = singal2[:,0]
fsig = np.fft.fft(sinal2)
```

On a final note, you FFT plot shows a horizontal line connecting the upper and lower halfs of the frequency spectrum. See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49613381/2994596) to address this problem. Since you mention that you really only need half the spectrum, you could also truncate the result to the first `N//2+1` points:

```
plt.plot( freq[0:len(freq)//2+1], np.abs(fsig[0:len(fsig)//2+1]))
```